# Is it necessary to use both Jenkins and GitHub?

Tags: jenkins, github, continuous-integration

My former web developer setup my site so that it uses Jenkins and GitHub.  I understand the very basics of GitHub and even less of Jenkins.  But in theory, when I make minor text changes to my website, can't GitHub manage the process of pushing those changes to the server?  Or is there some good reason that Jenkins is also involved?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It's not a must but using both Jenkins and Github will make your life easy. Github and Jenkins are two tools that help you to do different functions.

**Github** will mainly help you to manage your codebase, resolve conflicts, etc. So it will basically behave as a repository. You can commit your changes and get other's updates and always be up to date. There are tons of other advantages but I'll keep it simple for understanding purpose.

**Jenkins** is an open-source automation server. In your case, you can automate the product building. For example if you have a test environment or even when you deploy the changes t live, you can do all that with just a click. And you can separately build tests and live environments and With concepts like pipeline, you can even integrate the building with tests, etc.

But if you are talking about your local environment, yes git is enough because you can build the project manually. but in production have git and jenkins both will be a handy option.

[Read more on Jenkins](https://www.edureka.co/blog/what-is-jenkins/)